# How to get responses status list for call "progress"?

Tags: dailymotion-api

I use this url http://upload-XX.dailymotion.com/progress?uuid= to poll the progress of my current upload.

To have a correct management of the states I would need to know the list of possible states and their flow.

This information is not present in the documentation https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#file_upload-fields

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your feedback, we will add the information in the documentation.

Here is the different states:

```
starting +------+
   +            |
   |            +-----> error
   v            |
uploading +-----+
   +
   |
   v
 done
```